# How do you send an intent to specific contact in messaging app?

Tags: android

This has been asked before, "How do I send a message to a specific WhatsApp contact?" and previously the answer was that it was impossible.
However, as of July 2015, Google Now lets you say "OK Google send a WhatsApp message to FriendsName Hello". Like this GIF:
[image]

What is the intent Google Now is using in order to send it to **FriendsName specifically** (John Testo in the GIF above)?

Personally, I'm concerned with doing this for Telegram, but I know WhatsApp is more popular. So help with either is appreciated.

This will let me send "Hello" to Telegram, but then I'd have to select the recipient. How do I send "Hello" to a specific recipient?

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hello");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger");
```

Comment: did you find solution?